# Having common code for both phone and tablet Android

Tags: android, common-code

For our project we our supporting from android 2.3 onward on phone and as well as for tablets 3.0 onward.
   I would like to have common code base and UI for both. But found that from 3.0 onward. some classes like fragments, loaders are support where as below this version its not. So which would be the best practice to keep the code common (or maximize the common code).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: search for support package